# Group By a Specific Column

Tags: sql

I had this query that was working fine...

```
select a.action_id, a.request_date, a.customer_id from customer.actions a
inner join customer.customers c on c.id = a.customer_id
inner join customer.entities e on e.id = c.entity_id
where request_url like '%/test%'
order by a.request_date desc;
```

This returned +- 500 lines. Now I wanted to inner join with another table but it's returning like 4000 lines..

```
select a.action_id, a.customer_id, a.request_date, mp.payment_type from customer.actions a
inner join customer.customers c on c.id = a.customer_id
inner join customer.entities e on e.id = c.entity_id
inner join customer.mobile_payments mp on mp.customer_id = a.customer_id 
where request_url like '%/test%'
order by a.request_date desc;
```

[image]
I get duplicate records for every record on the mobile_payments table.
Group by does not work

How do I remove the duplicate `action_ids` ? `DISTINCT (a.action_id)` doesn't work

EDIT:

I just want the records from the customer.actions filtered by where request_url like '%/test%' and I want to get the payment type from the mobile_payments table. 1 for each action_id. When I do that I get duplicate actions ids.

Comment: Have you tried DISTINCT ?

Comment: They are not duplicates.  They are multiple matches in the additional table being joined in.  You need to specify what you want in the result set in this case.  You should also tag with the database you are using.

Comment: I just want the records from the `customer.actions` filtered by `where request_url like '%/test%'` and I want to get the payment type from the mobile_payments table. 1 for each action_id. When I do that I get duplicate actions ids.

Comment: Looks to me like a classic m:n problem. "Many customers have many mobile_payments". Thats why the records are so high. If a customer has 4 mobile payments you get 4 records etc.

Comment: so you need to analyze and understand your data. Filter your query on a single customer_id and look at the rows from `mobile_payments`. Which of the several `payment_type` are you expecting. The most recent payment?

Answer (score 0):

As accurately pointed out by J0eBl4ck in comment, the issue is that you are joining to the payments table on the sole condition of matching customer.  Think of it like this.  You have a credit card for purchases over 10 years.  Each month you make a payment, so you have 120 payments made under your account.

Is there some other basis you are joining to the payment table?  You have an action ID?  Does that mean something?  Do you intend to get a payment associated to that specific action?  Is there such a relationship where it would be

customer -> payments joined on customer_id AND action_id?

A secondary option is to apply a sub-query from the payments table grouped by the customer id so it only returns a single row, this way it does not distort your overall record count.  You may need to adjust the underlying criteria some, but this should help you look into final resolution to your needs.

```
select 
        a.action_id, 
        a.customer_id, 
        a.request_date, 
        mp.payment_type 
    from 
        customer.actions a
            inner join customer.customers c 
                on a.customer_id = c.id
                inner join customer.entities e 
                    on c.entity_id = e.id
            inner join 
            -- this "PQ" Pre-Query is by customer ID and example
            -- to get the payment type based on whatever the most recent
            -- transaction in first position
            ( select mp.customer_id,
                     mp.payment_type,
                     row_number() over (partition by mp.customer_id 
                                        order by mp.WhateverPrimaryKeyOrDateIs DESC ) as rowSeq
                from
                    customer.mobile_payments mp ) PQ
                -- so here, we are only joining on the FIRST (most recent due to descending)
                -- payment type applicable for the customer ID in question joined to
                on a.customer_id = PQ.customer_id
                AND PQ.rowSeq = 1
    where 
        request_url like '%/test%'
    order by 
        a.request_date desc;
```

Again, you WILL probably need to adjust the pre-query as we dont get the context association of payment to a given action.  Hopefully it will guide you in your final goal though.